# how to prevent the access to a website by the IP?

Tags: server, apache2, 19.04, virtualhost

How can I prevent the access to a website by the IP? I have a Dedicated Server with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Apache. I want to prevent the access to my website by IP. I would like only virtual hosts to be accessible.

Comment: I already change to 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 000-default.conf file and set up a [Mod Rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This will only work if you use more than one virtual host.

Comment: This is only a half answer and doesn't answer exactly how to do this.